# Need to parse through largish (15k records) in PHP, do some other manipualtions. Suggestions?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Client has a financial services website where he gets CSV spreadsheets full of leads every morning. Usually they are about 10k - 15k records in each sheet.  What he would like to do is upload that spreadsheet, have the server parse through it, check his database for duplicate leads, insert them into his database, check the records against an external API, and email the qualified leads.

Right now I have built him a makeshift utility that does all this but it would seem the server and the database are overstressed by doing this many.  He has to cut them up into 1000 record packets but this annoys him. It uploads the file, loops through the spreadsheet and does everything above except it just can't handle that much at a time.

So my question is does anybody have some general advice about how you might handle something like this, anything you might consider for something like this?  In particular being able to upload a single file and then not have to worry about it the rest of the day would put a huge smile on his face.

Here is how I'm currently processing these records (don't laugh):

```
<?php
//standard php file upload handler
include("upload.inc.php");

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

mysql_select_db("database",$conn);



if($_FILES['csvFile']['name']) {

$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/files/";

list($file,$errMsg) = upload('csvFile',$upload_dir,'');



// clear the db table

$sql = "DELETE FROM tempTable";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");



// process the file

$row = 1;

$fileName = $upload_dir . $file;

if (($handle = fopen($fileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

$num = count($data);

// write the data to mysql duplicate checker table

$sql = "INSERT INTO tempTable (process_date,firstname,middlename,lastname,ssn,dob,dl_number,dl_state,gender,military_active,amount_requested,residence_type,residence_length,address1,address2,city, state,zip,phone_home,phone_cell,contact_time,email,ip_addr,pay_frequency,net_income,first_payday,second_payday,employment_status,employer_name,job_title,hire_date,phone_work,phone_work2, bank_name,account_type,direct_deposit,reference1_firstname,reference1_lastname,reference1_relationship,phone_reference1,reference2_firstname,reference2_lastname,reference2_relationship, phone_reference2,routing_no,account_no) VALUES

('".mysql_escape_string($data[0])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[1])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[2])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[3])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[4])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[5])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[6])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[7])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[8])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[9])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[10])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[11])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[12])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[13])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[14])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[15])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[16])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[17])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[18])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[19])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[20])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[21])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[22])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[23])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[24])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[25])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[26])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[27])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[28])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[29])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[30])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[31])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[32])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[33])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[34])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[35])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[36])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[37])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[38])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[39])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[40])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[41])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[42])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[43])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[44])."',

'".mysql_escape_string($data[45])."')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");

$numRows++;

//echo "<br>";

}

fclose($handle);



// now look for duplicates

$sql_1 = "SELECT account_no,count(*) FROM tempTable GROUP BY account_no";

$result_1 = mysql_query($sql_1) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");

while(list($acct,$numcount) = mysql_fetch_row($result_1)) {

// if there is more than one delete all of them

if($numcount>1) {

//echo "acct: $acct, num: $numcount<br>";

$toBeRemoved+=$numcount;

$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM tempTable WHERE(account_no = '$acct')";

$result_delete = mysql_query($sql_delete) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");

}

else {

//echo "acct: $acct, num: $numcount<br>";

}

}



// now remove the duplicates who are already in the customer table

$sql_2 = "SELECT account_no FROM customerTable";

$result_2 = mysql_query($sql_2) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");

while(list($acct) = mysql_fetch_row($result_2)) {

//echo "acct: $acct, num: $numcount<br>";

$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM tempTable WHERE(account_no = '$acct')";

$result_delete = mysql_query($sql_delete) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");

}

// now send the user to the new page with more options
Header("Location: finish.php");

}





}

?>



<html>
<body>
<?php 

if(!empty($_GET['msg'])) {

$msg = $_GET['msg'];

echo "<strong>$msg</strong>";

}

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload CSV File: <input type="file" name="csvFile" size="30">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 10k-15k doesn't sound like very much to me - a job of a couple of seconds for the RDBMS or script. Post your code and we can help to optimize it.

Comment: CSV is easy to handle, why not split up the file while reading it? Lines 1-1000, second run lines 1001-2000 etc.

Comment: 15k records is NOT a lot. If you were taking about millions, I would be worried. It sounds like your method of manipulating the data is relatively unoptimized. Post how you're processing the records.

Comment: Thanks I'll post the details of how I'm processing

Comment: You could use unique and have it fail to insert instead of manually checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Background job runner to do something like this. I have been doing this alot lately

https://github.com/seatgeek/djjob

http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/djjob-a-php-port-of-delayed_job

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try timing some of your db queries and batching them together. Might be one of them is slowing everything down.

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure both `tempTable.account_no` and `customerTable.account_no` are indexed (they probably are already primary keys). You may also want to `ALTER TABLE temptable ENGINE=MEMORY;`, which makes MySQL [work in memory only](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) (no writes to disk, but the table contents are lost on server shutdown).

2- To import your CSV file into a table:

```
ALTER TABLE tempTable DISABLE KEYS; -- otherwise, MySQL recomputes indexes after each line is inserted
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'yourfile.csv' INTO TABLE tempTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ;
ALTER TABLE tempTable ENABLE KEYS; -- recompute all indexes in one go
```

You certainly need to customise the `LOAD DATA` command to [match the exact format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) of your input file.

3- To delete duplicates:

```
DELETE tempTable.*
FROM tempTable

-- match with the list of duplicates
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT account_no
    FROM tempTable
    GROUP BY account_no
    COUNT(account_no) > 1
) AS duplicates
    ON duplicates.account_no = tempTable.account_no

-- match with records in customerTable
LEFT JOIN customerTable
    ON customerTable.account_no = tempTable.account_no

-- records with either duplicates, or with a match in customerTable
WHERE duplicates.account_no IS NOT NULL OR customerTable.account_no IS NOT NULL;
```